# Why is there gap on left of slides?

Tags: css

[image]

If you look at the image above, you will see there is gap on the left of the slide. According to my coding there should be no gap and the slide should display at the center of the header.

The side is live at http://snapnsolve.com/

Can anyone figure out  why this is happening?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div with class `.intro` is aligned in the center and has a `max-width of 980px`. Therefore everything in the div will be positioned according to this max-width.

If you want it wider, just make it larger or position it in a different way (e.g. relative values).

Comment: The slide inside should still show at the center. It was showing at the center before, all of a sudden it started showing more in the right side.

Comment: Now I get it :) it's the margin: 0 auto in .intro. Try setting that to  margin:0;

Comment: That did work right? If I look at your website and the image below I see the gap is narrowed. The left side of the image is transparent, If you want it more to the left than you have to strip that from the image.